# LEDs in 8x8 matrix triggered in unexpected order

Tags: python, electronics, adafruit

I have bought a pre-built 8x8 LED matrix powered by an ht16k33 and connected it to a Raspberry Pi 3b. I have created the following test program, which should turn on each of the LEDs of an 8x8 matrix in turn:

```
import time
import board
import busio

from adafruit_ht16k33 import matrix

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

matrix = matrix.Matrix8x8(i2c)

while True:
    matrix.fill(0)
    for x in range(0, matrix.columns):
        for y in range(0, matrix.rows):
            matrix.pixel(x, y, 1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

The program does this, but the LEDs are controlled in an unexpected order. I'd expect the matrix columns to be lit up in this pattern:

12345678

This is the order in which they are being triggered instead - the "last" column lights up first, followed by the opposite one, then each sequential column:

23456781

I've tried different I2C address settings with the same result - I've also tried starting x from 1 and counting to columns + 1, but this just results in the last column not being lit at all.

Is this a coding issue, a wiring issue, a bad component, or expected functionality that I don't understand yet?

Comment: `I'd expect the matrix columns to be lit up in this pattern: 12345678` ... is that order specified in the LED matrix datasheet?

Comment: try range 0 to 7

Comment: @jsotola it's a 1088BS LED matrix, the datasheet I found shows the columns and rows being numbered sequentially. If I limit the range to 0-7 instead the program still works, but only part of the matrix is illuminated.

Comment: You might try changing the `for x in range(0, matrix.columns):` to `for x in (7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6):` to see if that is correct.